# Exceptions from HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I am developing against an API which sends back proper HTTP status codes (401 not authorized, etc) - but this is causing my code (using HttpURLConnection) to throw an IOException when I try to look at the status code.

This is a problem, because different "error code" http status codes mean different things, but they're all getting wrapped up into an IOException that comes from HttpURLConnection.

Is there any way to prevent HttpURLConnection from throwing these exceptions? Am I better off repackaging HttpClient 4.1 and using that for my client? I know Google is pushing HttpURLConnection, so that's what I was using... but this issue is making me rethink my decision.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's when you try to look at the status code? The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) say:

> If the HTTP response indicates that an error occurred, getInputStream() will throw an IOException.

but that's only for `getInputStream`. You should still be able to get the status code with [`getResponseCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) unless you really do have some sort of I/O problem. If this is really a problem, can you post the stack trace?